# I want to learn how to program by orienting myself to the task of reverse engineering

Tags: decryption, encryption, tools

I have to learn programming from scratch and I want to orient my learning in order to be able to reverse engineer to break obfuscators. It would be helpful if you could recommend me what languages, tools and skills I should learn and provide me with your favorite sources: blogs, books, articles, Wikipedia; whatever you find suitable.
In my search I found procedural reverse engineering material but they were really old (2005; 2014), none should work as I expect nowadays, or so I interpret.